# Limit the access of a function to once every 24 hours (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to limit the access of a function i've created to once every 24 hour based on the users IP address.
I would also like the PHP script to delete the MySQL record if it's older than 24 hours.

If the user already has used the function within 24 hours, show them a message and prevent the script from continue running.

If the user already has used the function but 24 hours has passed since he used the function, delete the MySQL record and let the script continue running.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$con=mysqli_connect("domain.com.mysql","domain_com","domain_password","domain_database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ipblock WHERE ip='".$ip."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));

if($ip == $row['ip']) //and code for checking how old the record is
{
// The user has used the function within 24 hours, kill the script.
echo "Come back in 24 hours";
exit;
}
else
{
// Looks clear, let them use the function
$MyFunction = true;
}
?>
```

I'm lost and as you can see i am also missing some statements for deleting old records (-24 hours)..

Could anyone provide me with an example of how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you lost? Are you getting errors in your code? Where is your code?

Comment: Look into MySQL Events and Triggers

Comment: check `event scheduler` in mysql..

Comment: Check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: I have updated this post now, included a code i tried to use before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly store the IP and Access time as a pair in a table. Then you check is simple to see if there are any records in existence where the IP matches and the timestamp is less than 24 hours ago.

Before the function runs, complete an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, and have the IP address as the primary key in the table.

The removal of old entries is then less of a priority and you can schedule this to be whenever convinient and remove entries where the access time is greater than 24 hours ago.

Store the access time as a myqsl date time, and do the comparison using the where clause:

```
WHERE accesstime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a table with function load
Store IP address and timestamp
When user loads the page, before running the function, select for IP adress and timestamp < 24 hours previous. 
If you run the function: Store the users IP

No need to delete older records. But you could lik this to the verification function: delete all events older than 24 hours whenever the function is called for. Or set a cronjob to run every 12 hours to delete all older function load records

Basically, you can just create a timestamp field in the database. Then you compare using timediff() the stored values with the value of now().

Comment: But how can i check if the timestamp is < 24 hours previous? and in what format should i store the current time and date?